# Prove $P(A|B)+P(\bar{A}|B)=1$

Tags: probability

How can I prove the following statement:

$$P(A|B)+P(\bar{A}|B)=1$$

I did the following:

$P(A|B)+P(\bar{A}|B)= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} + \frac{P(\bar{A} \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A\cap B)+ P(\bar{A} \cap B)}{P(B)}$

But I don't know how to connect the fact that since $A$ and $\bar{A}$ are mutually exclusive, it becomes $\frac{P(B)}{P(B)} = 1$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know the formula for conditional probability?

Comment: $(A \cap B) \cup (\bar{A} \cap B) = B$

Comment: @PaulinaMora What you did is correct, why do you have a doubt ?

Comment: You need to review the set theory.

Answer (score 1):

According to [The Probability of Not Mutually Exclusive Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Not_mutually_exclusive_events):
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
When two events are mutually exclusive, $A \cap B = \varnothing$, $P(A \cap B) = 0$, hence:
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$$
Now that $(A \cap B) \cap (\bar A \cap B) = [(A \cap B) \cap \bar A] \cap B = [(A \cap \bar A) \cap B] \cap B = (\varnothing \cap B) \cap B = \varnothing$, $A \cap B$ and $\bar A \cap B$ are two mutually exclusive events, naturally:
$$P(A \cap B) + P(\bar A \cap B) = P[(A \cap B) \cup (\bar A \cap B)]$$
Because $(A \cap B) \cup (\bar A \cap B) = (A \cup \bar A) \cap B = B$,
we have $P(A \cap B) + P(\bar A \cap B) = P(B)$.

Eventually, we have $P(A \mid B) + P(\bar A \mid B) = 1$.